# installing rvm results in bash: no such file or directory

Tags: ruby, windows, bash, cygwin, rvm

I have installed cygwin with the latest binaries for bash, curl, etc.

Everytime I run the command `curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`, I get the same result:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   184  100   184    0     0    114      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   136
100 22726  100 22726    0     0  12556      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  157k
Downloading https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/1.26.3.tar.gz
Downloading https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/releases/download/1.26.3/1.26.3.tar.gz.asc
bash: line 400: /cygdrive/c/Program: No such file or directory
Warning, RVM 1.26.0 introduces signed releases and automated check of signatures when GPG software found.
Assuming you trust Michal Papis import the mpapis public key (downloading the signatures).

GPG signature verification failed for '/home/euser/.rvm/archives/rvm-1.26.3.tgz' - 'https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/releases/download/1.26.3/1.26.3.tar.gz.a            sc'!
try downloading the signatures:

    gpg2 --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys D39DC0E3

or if it fails:

    command curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | gpg2 --import -

the key can be compared with:

    https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc
    https://keybase.io/mpapis
```

I think the main issue is the "no such file or directory" but it might be a red herring. I have already installed all the certificates according to the commands above. Since the 'bash' program is an executable I am unaware how to track down the file path that is causing this error - could be anything.

Does someone know how I could resolve this?

Comment: That certainly seems like it could be the issue. Download the script to a file. Find that line and put quotes around `${rvm_gpg_command}` on it. Then try it again and see if it works. If it does then file a bug with rvm about needing to fix that.

Comment: which script do you mean and where would i find it? Also how would i merge it back in?

Comment: oh, i just realized that the URL is the script...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two problems here

1. they did not quote a variable `${rvm_gpg_command}`
2. your path to `gpg` has a space in it

One of these needs to be fixed. The quick fix would be to install the Cygwin
package `gnupg`.

Also, I [did you a solid](http://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/pull/3161).

---

*Update by @mpapis:* and it is merged, to use it run:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash
```

the `-s stable` part has to be removed from command
(it is not yet merged into **stable**).

Answer (score 1):

You can download the signature and import manually:

curl -#LO https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc

gpg --import mpapis.asc

This will resolve your problem.